# how to write binary copy of structure array to file

Tags: c, arrays, file, pointers, struct

I would like to write a binary image of a structure array to a binary file. I have tried this so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define NUM 256

const char *fname="binary.bin";


typedef struct foo_s {
    int intA;
    int intB;
    char string[20];
}foo_t;



void main (void)
{
    foo_t bar[NUM];

    bar[0].intA = 10;
    bar[0].intB = 999;
    strcpy(bar[0].string,"Hello World!");

    Save(bar);
    printf("%s written succesfully!\n",fname);
}

int Save(foo_t* pData)
{
    FILE *pFile;
    int ptr = 0;
    int itr = 0;

    pFile = fopen(fname, "w");
    if (pFile == NULL) {
        printf("couldn't open %s\n", fname);
        return;
    }
    for (itr = 0; itr<NUM; itr++) {
        for (ptr=0; ptr<sizeof(foo_t); ptr++)
        {
            fputc((unsigned char)*((&pData[itr])+ptr), pFile);
        }
        fclose(pFile);
    }  
}
```

but the compiler is saying `aggregate value used where an integer was expected fputc((unsigned char)*((&pData[itr])+ptr), pFile);` and I don't quite understand why, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ensure file is opened in binary mode.

   ```
   // pFile = fopen(fname, "w");
   pFile = fopen(fname, "wb");
   ```
2. Cast to `char *` pointer before indexing.  Original code indexes by the `sizeof(pData[itr])`. [Edit] and then dereferenced the type - then tries to cast to `unsigned char` @R Sahu

   ```
   //fputc((unsigned char)*((&pData[itr])+ptr), pFile);
   unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *) (&pData[itr]);
   fputc(p[ptr], pFile);
   ```
3. As @R Sahu pointed out: `fclose()` should be moved outside the loops.

Minor:

1. Recommend passing `NUM` is as argument to `save()`.
2. `foo_t bar[NUM];` is not fully initialized.
3. The non-loop solution is

   ```
   if (fwrite(pData, sizeof(*pData), NUM, pFile) == NUM) Success();
   ```
4. Suggest making `const`: `int Save(const foo_t* pData)
5. Better to use `size_t` for `ptr` & `itr`

Comment: See [@R Sahu](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25418202/2410359) concerning mis-placed `fclose()`.  Also that answer's explanation concerning the compiler error is more correct.  The solution is the same.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem 1**

Use the right mode for opening the file.

```
pFile = fopen(fname, "wb");
```

**Problem 2**

The call to `fclose` is in the wrong place.

```
for (itr = 0; itr<NUM; itr++) {
  for (ptr=0; ptr<sizeof(foo_t); ptr++)
  {
    fputc((unsigned char)*((&pData[itr])+ptr), pFile);
  }
  fclose(pFile);
}
```

You are closing the file after writing out the data of the first `foo_t`. Subsequent calls will result in undefined behavior since you will be calling `fputc` using a `FILE*` that has been closed.

The call to `fclose` must be moved out of the loops.

```
for (itr = 0; itr<NUM; itr++) {
  for (ptr=0; ptr<sizeof(foo_t); ptr++)
  {
    fputc((unsigned char)*((&pData[itr])+ptr), pFile);
  }
}
fclose(pFile);
```

**Problem 3**

The way you are trying to access a byte in the loops is incorrect. Here are the loops:

```
for (itr = 0; itr<NUM; itr++) {
  for (ptr=0; ptr<sizeof(foo_t); ptr++)
  {
    fputc((unsigned char)*((&pData[itr])+ptr), pFile);
  }
}
```

Here's the line you are trying to get a byte.

```
    fputc((unsigned char)*((&pData[itr])+ptr), pFile);
                           ^           ^
                           This is of type `foo_t*`

    fputc((unsigned char)*((&pData[itr])+ptr), pFile);
                          ^                 ^
                          This pointer arithmetic is done on `foo_t*`.
                          It is not pointer arithmetic done on `char*`.
                          You are going to run into out of bound memory access
                          very quickly.

    fputc((unsigned char)*((&pData[itr])+ptr), pFile);
                         ^                  ^
                         This is dereferencing a `foo_t*`, which
                         means it is of type `foo_t`.
```

You are getting the compiler error since you are trying to cast a `foo_t` to an `unsigned char`.

To save a `foo_t`, you can take two approaches. You can use `fwrite` to save an entire `foo_t` in one call.

```
for (itr = 0; itr<NUM; itr++) {
  fwrite(&(pData[itr]), sizeof(foo_t), 1, pFile);
}
```

If you must write each byte using `fputc`, which I don't think is needed, you will have to change your code a little bit.

The following should work:

```
for (itr = 0; itr<NUM; itr++) {
  cp = (char*)&pData[itr];  // Declare char* cp in the function.
  for (ptr=0; ptr<sizeof(foo_t); ptr++)
  {
    fputc(cp[ptr], pFile);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To write into the binary file you need to open the file in w+b mode.
and then use fwrite to write into the file.
It should work.

```
pFile = fopen(fname, "w+b");
```

Instead of fputc use fwrite.

```
fwrite ((foo_t *)&pData[itr], sizeof(foo_t), 1, pFile);
```

Comment: `error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
       fwrite(pData[itr][ptr], sizeof(foo_t), 1, pFile);`

Comment: dont use the inner for loop.

Answer (score 0):

i think all you need to do is just write it.

```
foo_t fooarry[SOME_SIZE];

fd = open(fname, O_WRONLY);
write(fd, fooarry, SOME_SIZE * sizeof(foo_t));
```

UPDATE:
if you want to use file stream, go like this:

```
fwrite(fooarry, siezeof(foo_t), SOME_SIZE, pFile);
```